# Why is molar mass of a substance and atomic mass number usually the same?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I recognize what atomic mass represent and what molar mass represents by why is it that a substances molar mass and it’s atomic mass are usually the same number

Ex: chlorine has an atomic mass of 35.453 u and a molar mass of 35.453 g/mol

Comment: I like that tinge of incertitude ("usually"). Indeed, the skill of not making overly broad generalizations is rather important in a scientist. Now to the point. Long story short, this is because the units (u and g/mol) are not facts of nature; they were invented by humans, and chosen so as to be convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term mole is a short form of the German word *Molekül* which was coined by Ostwald in 1890s. At that time, the "atomic mass unit" did not exist. The common term at that time was gram atomic mass or gram-molecule. The original meaning of so-called was defined to be equal one gram molecule i.e, the mass of a molecule expressed in grams. Atomic mass unit came into use by the 1950s.

These values match by definition not by coincidence. Here is how Ostwald coined the concept of a "mole". In those times molecules weights were determined by colligative properties. This is a snapshot of Findlay "Principles of Inorganic Chemistry" (translation of Ostwald's work)

[image]

Comment: What is the unit of gram atomic mass? Gram or Gram/mol? I think it is gram, but I asked many people and they say it is gram/mol, but gram atomic was even used before mole (I guess).

Comment: In older times, it must be just grams as the name indicates.